# I am having trouble parsing and getting value wanted

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, parsing, cheerio

What I want to do is parse through the html and grab this offerId. It is inside of an href link so what I plan on doing is just converting it into a string and I will do the rest later. First what I need to do is parse and get that href. I am trying to get it from this website https://www.walmart.com/ip/Pokemon-Assorted-Lot-of-50-Single-Cards-Any-Series/127446742. if you ctrl-f and type offerId you will find that href I am looking for.There are a couple of them but if I am able to figure out how to get one of them getting a different one shouldn't be too hard. If you need any extra clarification please lmk.

```
function getOfferId (err, data){
    const $ = cheerio.load(item.urltest);
        const offerId1 = $('.seller-name').attr('href');
        console.log(offerId1)
    
}

getOfferId()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this using Axios, one could really use any http client (node-fetch etc), I decided to simply iterate over the links in the page and do a regex test for "offerid=", we can then parse the hrefs and pull out the offerids.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require("axios");

async function getOfferIds(url) {
    const { data: html } = await axios.get(url, { headers: { "User-Agent": "Axios"}});

    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    
    const linkList = $('a').map( (index, element) => {
        return { href: $(element).attr('href'), text: $(element).text() };
    }).toArray().filter(({ href }) => /offerid=/i.test(href));
    
    console.log("getOfferIds: linkList:", linkList);
    
    const offerIds = linkList.map( ({ href, text }) => { 
        return { text, href, offerId: new URL(href, "a://").searchParams.get("offerId") };
    });
    
    console.log("getOfferIds: offerIds:", offerIds);
    return offerIds;
}

async function test() {
    const offerIds = await getOfferIds("https://www.walmart.com/ip/Pokemon-Assorted-Lot-of-50-Single-Cards-Any-Series/127446742");
    console.log("test: offerIds:", offerIds);
}

test();
```

Comment: how would I implement this inside of an async function. Since I need to implement this inside of my code. So I already have an async function with all my requests and I need to put this one inside but when I would run this it would just get stuck on this function

Comment: You should be able to nest asynchronous functions without any problems. There's no reason an asynch. function can't call another one! Also, we could change this out so getOfferIds simply accepts html. At this point there's no need for it to be async.

Comment: when I put it in my code it doesn't console log anything an goes to the next step. Also I need to store the offerId in a variable so I can call on it later in my code.

Comment: You should be able to use the offer id later on in an async function, using the await keyword will do this. As for the console.log not displaying, I'm not sure what could cause that,  I'd maybe try to attach a debugger or add some more log statements!

Comment: (node:4876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: offerIds is not defined
I get that error whenever I try to console log or refer to the offerIds variable outside of the async function

Comment: The offerIds variable should be returned by the getOfferIds function using the await syntax. Is your calling function asynchronous too? Thanks!

Comment: I just want to get the actual idea . So I want to place offerIds[0] into a variable that I can call onto later.

Comment: You could use a .then() call on the returned promise from getOfferIds to save the offerIds to a global variable. This could then be accessed later.

Comment: How and where would you put the .then

Comment: Oh you can do something like getOfferIds(url).then(ids => offerId = ids[0]). The global offerId variable would then be populated.

Comment: I get  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: getOfferIds(...).then(...).setRunningStatus is not a function when I run that function you just sent.

Comment: Hmmm, that's strange.. I'm probably just running a different environment.

Comment: I have been having this trouble the entire day. I have a function and I have variables inside and I am not able to use those variables outside of my function.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the page as a string you can search it for the desired text by using regular expression.
Here is an example:

```
const regexp = /offerid=(.+?)\W/gi;
const result = [...stringPage.matchAll(regexp)];
  
console.log('first found id:', result[0][1])
//first found id: 8911563635265
```

Note: the "..." before the variable are necessary to convert the returned object into an array; making looping much easier.
I hope this can help you get started.